# GraphQL Client for C# - status not found

Tags: c#, .net, azure, graphql

that's my first topic here.
I searched few articles, but I can not find any working solution.
I want do reach data from GraphQL API from my Azure Function App.
I prepared a function, time trigerred on every 1 minute.
I'm still getting response:

> The HTTP request failed with status code NotFound

What I'm doing wrong? Query?

That's the documentation:
[API Documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZZPW1qy0rukBFgNuyyBkL1aitibNO8s/view?usp=sharing)

That's the respond from Postman:

```
{
    "data": {
        "solarPowerUtilization": [
            {
                "timestamp": "2022-07-22T10:37:16.8036596Z",
                "sensorCount": 2,
                "result": 0.1215339233038348,
                "measurementUnit": "%",
                "latestObservationTime": "2022-07-22T10:36:01Z",
                "earliestObservationTime": "2022-07-22T10:36:01Z",
                "realEstate": {
                    "id": "SomeData",
                    "class": "RealEstate",
                    "aliasId": "4057",
                    "popularName": "SomeData",
                    "address": "SomeData",
                    "solarPowerCapacity": 33900
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Function:

```
[FunctionName("AmfFlowIngestion")]
public async Task GetData([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *",
    #if DEBUG
        RunOnStartup = true
    #endif
    )] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{

    try
    {
        GraphQLHttpClientOptions graphQLHttpClientOptions = new()
        {
            EndPoint = new Uri(amfApiUrl, UriKind.Absolute),
        };

        GraphQLHttpClient graphQLClient = new(graphQLHttpClientOptions, new GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
        graphQLClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", amfApiKey);

        GraphQLHttpRequest request = new()
        {
            Query = @"
                query {
                    solarPowerUtilization(realEstateId: ""4057"") {
                        timestamp
                        sensorCount
                        result
                        measurementUnit
                        latestObservationTime
                        earliestObservationTime
                        realEstate {
                            id
                            class
                            aliasId
                            popularName
                            address
                            solarPowerCapacity
                        }
                    }
                }"
        };

        var response = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<Data>(request);

        log.LogInformation(response.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

}

Model

```
public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("solarPowerUtilization")]
        public SolarPowerUtilization[] SolarPowerUtilization { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("solarEnergyProduction")]
        public SolarEnergyProduction[] SolarEnergyProduction { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SolarPowerUtilization
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sensorCount")]
        public long SensorCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public double Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("measurementUnit")]
        public string MeasurementUnit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("latestObservationTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset LatestObservationTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("earliestObservationTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset EarliestObservationTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("realEstate")]
        public RealEstate RealEstate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SolarEnergyProduction
    {
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public long Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fromDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset FromDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("toDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset ToDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("measurementUnit")]
        public string MeasurementUnit { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sensorCount")]
        public long SensorCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("latestObservationTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset LatestObservationTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantityKind")]
        public string QuantityKind { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("placementContext")]
        public string PlacementContext { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("realEstate")]
        public RealEstate RealEstate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RealEstate
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("class")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("aliasId")]
        public string AliasId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("popularName")]
        public string PopularName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("solarPowerCapacity")]
        public long SolarPowerCapacity { get; set; }
    }
```